# google search results widget

Tags: google-search, google-widget

I'm looking for a widget for google search where I can set the search query and avoid user to change it. Even more I wuould like user can't see the search query at all. So he can see only the results of the search. Also I whant to set search type as 'News'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of incomplete: I am not sure who is your user, just someone who accessess your website or someone on your computer? Depending on who the user is, you can:

1. use a http://google.com homepage with your own search query, for example, http://www.google.com/search?q=lolcats
2. to use a query pointing to news search use something like this, ?hl=en&q=iraq&tbm=nws
3. in conjunction with a customized version of a browser (for example Opera) with user javascript hiding/disabling the search query (using CSS !important definitions)
4. while blocking additional JS behaviors of google by blocking the http://www.google.com/extern_js/* with adblocker

If your user is a website visitor, you can easily do the above point #1 in an iframe, perhaps also implementing point #3 with some script operating on the page outside of the google iframe; point 4 is impossible to implement, as far as I know, for a website user. However you can delete most spam and blogs on Google search by adding -com (or in url q=lolcats+-com respectively when searching for i has my tail lolcats) to your search terms.

If you need, I can post here a complete user script blocking certain features on google website [in my Opera browser], so that you have some reference for editing yours.